# Magento catalog url rewrites undo

Tags: magento-enterprise, url-rewrite

Is it possible to Undo Magento Catalog URL rewrite?
By accident this happened and I was wondering if it´s possible to undo this and then have the old URLs back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the new url in Catalog->Url Management and delete it. And make sure you manually add the old url back.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this in bulk? It seems like Magento changed all products after a certain date and gave it new URLs after changing the images.

Comment: From the UI you cannot do it in bulk. You will have to create a script. Unfortunately I don't have one.

Comment: Thanks Marius, I will look into that and post an update how i go. Do you know if I run the script will all the internal references update automatically?